# Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, google-analytics

I am totally lost here.

I have google analytics in my application to see how many users goto the detailview from my **UITableView**

i added the Google Analytics code in the viewDidLoad method as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    /*
    some code
    */

    NSError *error;
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-********-*" dispatchPeriod:10 delegate:nil];     
    if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/DetailView" withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
    NSLog(@"Track Detail PageView Error %@ %@",error,[error userInfo]);
    }
}
```

When i try the app on my device, the app freezes showing the following error.

**ERROR**

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
Xcode could not locate source file: GANTracker.m (line: 245)
```

I just cannot understand the error because there is no file called GANTracker.m in the google analytics package.

Another strange thing this error does not happen always, happens once in 10 times or something.

Its a library file and a header file.

Can some1 help me out ?

Comment: Don't be misled by the message about GANTracker.m. It's probably a message from the debugger that tries to show the location where the application has crashed but it's not the cause of the crash. Please paste the full stack trace of the crash into your question. Then we'll have much more information to help you.

Comment: that was all the information that was shown in the console. 
When i commented out the "Google Analytics" part in my code, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in many cases measn that you try to access to already realesed object. Try to set breakpoints and recognize where app crashes.

Comment: From what i read so far, the applicatio has already crashed and XCode is trying to help me out to check where it has crashed. But could not find the source file. Hence the file not found error msg.

Comment: @sherilyn: the application does not crash always. It crashes once in 10 times. So it is very difficult to debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` happened when you try to send a message to a variable already release.
You didn't show enough code so I think you should check this point.

- You should call `[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID` one time in you application not every time when user opens the View. Move this code to `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application`
- Release GANTracker when you application stop running.

[This is tutorial](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/)

Comment: I assumed, that if we are going to check statistics for different views, we should call [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID in both the places.

Comment: Hence i called [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID once in applicationDidFinishLaunching as i am collecting stats for how many launch the application as well.

Comment: Based on your advice, I will remove the DetailView and check it out

Comment: When you call [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID it will initialize the global variable then you don't need to call it again unless you release it. In this library they use Singleton pattern